# IllegalAccessError: org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader

Tags: java, jboss, lucene

I am trying to use Lucene search for my utility . The application is running on jboss and the search code is written in an ejb bean.

```
public List<String> textSearch(String text,String folder,String subfolder) throws IOException, RemoteException{

    final String indexloc="/index/"+folder+"/"+subfolder;
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexloc))); 
            List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            String fileList; 
            try {
                   IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
                   TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(500, true);

                   Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "contents", analyzer).parse(text);
                   searcher.search(q, collector);
                   ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
                   for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
                        int docId = hits[i].doc;
                        Document d = searcher.doc(docId);

                        data.add(d.get("FileName"));

                    }
            }catch(ParseException pe)
            {}
             catch(Exception e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Error:" + e);
            }


            return data;
}
```

When application is calling the remote function present inside bean , I am getting following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader
at offlineMApackage.TextSearchSessionBean.textSearch(TextSearchSessionBean.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386)
at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:228)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:350)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:267)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:211)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:134)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invoke(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:650)
at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1029)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor309.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.invocation.unified.server.UnifiedInvoker.invoke(UnifiedInvoker.java:232)
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:891)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:697)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:551)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:232)
```

Please suggest something if anyone encountered similar problem..?

Answer (score 0):

Well my problem got solved by including lucene jars in the jboss lib folder and setting proper classpath.